# Задачи на Python

Tags: python

"Существует список цифр оканчивающийся нулём, вывести количество двоек в нем"

Я пытался написать через цикл while и условия if, elif, else

```
s=0
while True:
    a=int(input())
    if a !=0:
        s+=0
        break
    elif a==2:
        g=s+1
        print(g) 
    else:
        print(s)
```

Помогите разобраться

Comment: А е сли убрать g вообще и увеличивать s на единицу? И почему в первом условии НЕ равно? Принт нужен один раз после цикла.

Comment: Если у вас віполнится условие `if a != 0`, то часть 'elif a == 2' уже не будет выполняться никогда,так как 2 != 0.

Answer (score 3):

Цикл "While True" - плохая практика.
Типовое решение типичных задач:

```
counter = 0
while (val := input()) != '0':
    if (val == '2'):  counter += 1
print(counter)
```

В данном выражении используется <strike>слоновый</strike> **моржовый** оператор **:=**, при помощи которого запоминаем переменную на этапе ввода. Остальное, думаю понятно.

Comment: Долго думал, что за "слоновый оператор". Потом понял, что на самом деле "моржовый". Вот оригинал: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html  Вот перевод:  https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/555924/  Так на сегодня уже общепринято.

Comment: @passant, кстати, да моржовый))) Не знаю почему написал слоновый)) Видимо по телику слоны показывались и написал на автомате)))

Answer (score -1):

Обычно, для работы со списками используют цикл for. С его помощью можно пройтись по элементам списка. В моём примере переменная digit проходится по списку (т.е. сначала переменная digit == 0, потом digit == 2, digit == 4 и т.д.). После чего, происходит сравнение с помощью if, равна ли переменная digit двум. Если равна, то прибавляет однёрку в переменную counter.

Вот код, для решения вашей очень лёгкой задачи:

```
example_list = [0, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0]

counter = 0

for digit in example_list:

    if digit == 2:
        counter = counter + 1

print(f'В вашем коде {counter} двоек.')
```

Comment: Вашу переменную `list` следует переименовать. Имена переменных не должно совпадать с зарезервированными словами языка.

Comment: То, что сделано у вас, заменяется на один метод списка count. Но у автора **нет списка** в таком виде.

Comment: @gfd2 всё, исправил

Comment: @MBo не понял вас

Comment: "список цифр оканчивающийся нулём" - учебное задание требует вводить числа, пока не будет введёт ноль

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю. Я считаю, что «список цифр, оканчивающийся нулём», это буквально список цифр, в котором рандомные цифры и в конце ноль, как у меня в `example_list`. Не исключаю, что я в упор чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: В учебных заданиях часто требуют вводить числа с консоли одно за другим. Чтобы определить конец ввода, в данном случае нужно ввести ноль. Вводимые числа можно записывать в список, и потом обработать, как сделано у вас, а можно вообще списка не делать, а подсчитывать двойки по мере ввода. И ввод данных здесь - важная часть учебной задачи. (Да, в реальной работе такое практически не нужно)

Comment: @Mbo понял, дошло. Не знал что это требуют в учебных заданиях. Спасибо. Сверху уже опубликовали решение.